# How do you search a list, if the value is found follow the if-statement once, not for each value found

Tags: python, list, search

Problem is that for every value it finds it follows if-statement and either `print("Prime")` or
`print("Not prime")`, What I want is for it to search the list completely, if the value is found, `print("Not prime")` once, not for each value it finds, and if it's not found, I want it to `print("Prime")` once.
Code below:

```
inp1 = int(input("The following: "))
for i in range(2, inp1):
    rest = inp1 % i
    liste = [rest]
    if 0 in liste:
        print("Not prime")
    else:
        print("Prime")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a list. If `inp1 % i` is 0, the number is *not* prime; you can break out of the loop immediately. If the `inp1 % i` is not 0, the number *may* be prime; you have to stay in the loop and check the next value.

One often overlooked feature of a `for` loop is that it can take an `else` clause itself. The `else` clause executes if the loop exits "naturally", by exhausting its iterator. If you exit the loop with `break`, the `else` does not execute.

```
for i in range(2, inp1):
    if inp1 % i == 0:
        print("Not prime")
        break
else:
    print("Prime")
```

`Prime` will only be printed *once*, and only if the `break` statement is not used.

The same algorithm can be implemented with `any`:

```
if any(inp1 % i == 0 for i in range(2, inp1):
    print("Not prime")
else:
    print("Prime")
```

In this case, `any` only returns `True` if one of the conditions is true, after which it does not check any additional conditions.